# iOS 9.1 crash due to APAddressBook book (image not found)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash

I am using APAdressBook cocoapods. I am getting crash on iphone 9.1 version, with this error message:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/APAddressBook.framework/APAddressBook
>     Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5D501E04-C41B-42E8-A0CE-841ADB8A1526/......
>     Reason: image not found

Comment: Are you getting this when running the app? Have you run `pod install`, did it completed successfully? Can you give us the link to the APAdressBook pod, as I could not find it?

Comment: Yes, It completed successfully. and there is no issue in simulator and lower version of ios<9.1.

Comment: Might be caused by the pods framework not installing at the correct location. Chek Mike Ash's [article](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html) that explains `@rpath` and then check your build settings.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got a solution. To solve this issue, follow these steps:

1. Firstly remove workspace in your project and pod file.
2. Update your cocoa pods and system
3. Reinstall all pods
4. quit from Xcode and run it again